# get value of PersistentCookie in MVC Custom Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

i use MVC 4,my login action is like to this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(Account loginInfo, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (loginInfo.Username == "Ali" && loginInfo.Password == "110")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginInfo.Username, loginInfo.RememberMe);
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(loginInfo.Username, loginInfo.RememberMe);
            }
        }
        this.ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        ViewBag.Error = "Login faild! Make sure you have entered the right user name and password!";
        return View(loginInfo);
    }
```

now my question is:
how i can in any time chack a user checked RememberMe checkbox or Not,in otherwords get value of PersistentCookie?

**Two SOLUTIONS**:

**my solution**:

```
        var isPersistent = false;
        var authCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            isPersistent = ticket.IsPersistent;
        }
```

**ChunHao Tang Solution(with a little change)**:

```
var isPersistent  = ((System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity) User.Identity).Ticket.IsPersistent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Authorize] filter to check

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    return View();
}
```

or, you can use Request.IsAuthenticated to check a user checked rememberMe checkbox or Not.

Comment: this is incorrect,because Request.IsAuthenticated just specify which current request is authenticated!? and not extra information about RememberMe checked or Not!

Comment: to check user's Expiration Date

Comment: ((System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity)User.Identity).Ticket.Expiration.Date

Comment: very thanx  ChunHao Tang,i added 2 solution to question,please see that.